# How to create javascript bundle that includes `

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vue.js

I'm using vuejs. Creating components and would like to bundle these in asp.net

e.g.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/mybundle")              
.Include("~/Scripts/mycomponent.js");
```

My components looks like this:

```
Vue.component("acomponent", {
    template: `<div> 
                <p>acomponent</p>
            </div>`
});
```

But when I view the source of the bundle I see the error

run-time error JS1014: Invalid character: `

So bundling doesn't like the ` character, but I need this to wrap my template.
Is there a way around this?

Visual Studio 2019 v16.1.6

Comment: Seems like your toolchain doesn't support ES2015. You could fallback to using string concatenation instead of backticks.

Comment: Thanks, I looked into vuejs components, and I can wrap them in single quotes instead of backticks. But then I either have to put the template onto one line or use \n\ or concatenate. This isn't ideal as it affects readability of my templates. I'm suprised VS2019/.net 4.5 can't handle this

Comment: I'm a newbie to typescript. But it seems that if I convert my .js to .ts and import vue at the top

e.g. import { Vue } from '../../vue.js'

I get a .js file with the template wrapped in quotes. So I maintain readability in the .ts file.

The problem now is that the .js file has
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var vue_js_1 = require("../../vue.js");
at the top. And I now get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined"